# verilog if-statement using register

Tags: if-statement, verilog

Is there a difference between the following IF-statements?

```
reg SRR_read;
```

1:

```
if (SRR_read == 1'b1) begin
....
end
```

2:

```
if (SRR_read) begin
....
end
```

Comment: no, there is no difference in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, both constructs are equivalent.

The same way:

```
if (!inword)
  ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (inword == 0)
  ...
```

In some cases, the first construct makes more sense to someone reading the code than the second one. ([1800-2012 - IEEE Standard for SystemVerilog](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), ch. 11.4.7)